# $\sum^n_{r=0} (-1)^r C_r(1/2^{r}+3^r/2^{2r}+7^r/2^{3r}+\cdots\infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum^n_{r=0} (-1)^r C_r(1/2^{r}+3^r/2^{2r}+7^r/2^{3r}+\cdots\infty)$$ is equal to?
How to approach this problem?Hints please!!! BTW $C(r)$ stands for $(n)C(r)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $$\sum_{s=1}^\infty\left[\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr\left(-\dfrac{2^s-1}{2^s}\right)^r\right]$$

Now,

$$\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr\left(-\dfrac{2^s-1}{2^s}\right)^r=\left[1-\dfrac{2^s-1}{2^s}\right]^n=\left[\left(\frac12\right)^n\right]^s=\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)^s$$

Comment: What have you written as coefficient of 2 in the 3rd last expression? Its not visible!

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, Press 'Control ', '+'  a few times

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, Welcome! Btw, May I know the source?

Comment: Was solving some jee advanced model papers :-P..!